# In Eclipse IDE, how can I limit Backward/Forward History to the current file?

Tags: windows, eclipse

Currently it goes between files.

Comment: Limiting backward/forward history to the current file is a solution for a problem you forgot to tell. Why do you want this limitation?

Comment: No, I didn't forget to tell. The medium is for questions - not necessarily problems.

Comment: Your question has already been answered by an Eclipse developer. What I asked you was, where does this make sense? Are there other editors/IDEs where this exists?

Answer (score 3):

No.                You can not.